# Having solme logical error in my RegisterClass View?

Tags: django

**My models.py**

Here I am have registered_students in as many to many field to Registered Names to store all the students that have registered for the class

```
class RegisteredNames(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)


class LiveClass_details(models.Model):
    chapter_details = models.TextField(default='')
    mentor_id = models.ForeignKey(Mentor, max_length=30, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    no_of_students_registered = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    registered_students = models.ManyToManyField(RegisteredNames, null=True, blank=True)
    no_of_students_attended = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

This model is for registering a student

```
class RegisteredClass(models.Model):
    class_details = models.ForeignKey(LiveClass_details, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**my views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET', 'DELETE'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, ))
def RegisterClassId(request, id):
    print(request.method)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        print("in get method")
        if not models.RegisteredClass.objects.filter(class_details=models.LiveClass_details.objects.get(id=id), user=request.user).exists():
            print("in get method")
            registered_class = models.RegisteredClass.objects.create(class_details=models.LiveClass_details.objects.get(id=id), user=request.user)
            registered_class.save()
            registered_live_class = models.LiveClass_details.objects.get(id=id)
            registered_live_class.no_of_students_registered += 1
            registered_live_class.no_of_students_attended += 1
            # registered_live_class.save()
            print(request.user.username)
            registered_name = models.RegisteredNames(name=request.user.username)

            print('registered name : ', registered_name)
            registered_name.save()
            registered_live_class.registered_students.add(registered_name)
            registered_live_class.save()
        else:
            print("already registered")
            
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        print("in delete method")
        registered_class = models.RegisteredClass.objects.get(class_details=models.LiveClass_details.objects.get(id=id), user=request.user)
        print("registere_class : ", registered_class)
        registered_class.delete()
        registered_class.save()
        registered_live_class = models.LiveClass_details.objects.get(id=id)
        if(registered_live_class.no_of_students_registered != 0):
            registered_live_class.no_of_students_registered -= 1
            registered_live_class.no_of_students_attended -= 1
        registered_live_class.save()
        print('error here')
        registered_name = models.RegisteredNames.objects.get(name=request.user.username)
        print('error after registered name')
        print(registered_name)
        registered_name.delete()

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Here in this view i am getting error in Adding as well as deleting registered_names from my liveclass_api model , In delete request it is returning error like `RegisteredNames matching query does not exist.` and in Get request it is not able to add names in the registered_students model, needs help i am really stuck here

Comment: Why do you even need that `RegisteredNames` class? Just keep the m2m with the user model. Even if you need that class why does it store a _copy_ of the username instead of simply having a [one to one relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/#one-to-one-relationships) with the user model?

Comment: I was doing this because i want to extract the names of registered_students for a class, and i am not able to do that with User model, i was using User model only initially, as it is just giving me the ids